# responsivePriority to multiple columns

Tags: datatable

I am using responsive datatable. I have following columns.

```
<tr>
    <th>Data 1</th>
    <th>Data 2</th>
    <th>Data 3</th>
    <th>Data 4</th>
    <th>Data 5</th>
    <th>Data 6</th>
    <th>Data 7</th>
    <th>Data 8</th>
    <th>Data 9</th>
    <th>Data 10</th>                                
</tr>
```

I want to display `Data 6, 7, 8` on the child row. How to use responsivePriority ? I have done `{ responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 7 },` and it works. But now if I do `{ responsivePriority: 10002, targets: 8 }` only the `Data 9` goes under the child row. I can I make three columns go under the child row?

UPDATE: I never want to show those 3 columns in the parent row.

Comment: Your approach works for me. Or in one line you can use `{ responsivePriority: 10001, targets: [ 5, 6, 7] }`. But only one column at a time will be moved to the child row, as you shrink the width of your table - so you have to keep shrinking the table far enough for all 3 rows to move. And if you shrink beyond that, additional rows will also move. If that is not what you want, can you clarify in the question?

Comment: @andrewJames yes if I shrink the table the three column goes down, How can I expand the width of the other columns so that the column can move down? Is there any possible way to limit the numbers of columns to be displayed on the parent row?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying you want these three columns to only be shown as child data? Never in the parent row? If that is what you want, then don't use the Responsive extension - just use the standard [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) approach.

Comment: Whatever you _do_ want, please clarify it in the question, instead of clarifying with comments.

Comment: @andrewJames Yes you got me right, I never want those columns to be displayed on the parent row. I have updated my question.

Comment: OK thank you for the clarification. You can use the link I already provided for that. Ask a specific question if you have a specific problem using that approach.